# Why take up 21 bytes, on a 32-bit system, three pointers plus two numbers 5 * 4 = 20 (should be 20 bytes )

Tags: list, redis

Why take up 21 bytes, on a 32-bit system, three pointers plus two numbers 5 * 4 = 20 (should be 20 bytes ah)
Thank you for your answer!!!

https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/01chapter-9-reducing-memory-use/9-1-short-structures/9-1-1-the-ziplist-representation/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNqcw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your book counts the terminating `\0` byte at the end of `"one\0"` as overhead, bringing the total to 21.

Comment: Three pointers, two numbers, '\0', string, why not 3 * 4 + 2 * 4 + 1 + 3 = 24 bytes

Comment: The actual data you want to store, the three bytes 'o', 'n', 'e', do not count as overhead.